# Compare Dates in different format oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have dates in different format :

Date 1 : `30-JAN-14`

Date 2 : `2014-01-30 10:06:04.0`

I am trying to compare the two dates using the following :

```
to_char(date2,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MM:SS') <> to_char(date1,'dd-MON-YY')
```

But it is giving the following error for the date1 part :

```
Lietral does not match format String
```

I tried comparing them directly

```
date2<>date1
```

I am gtting the same error again

EDIT : Date2 is varchar and Date1 is DATE

Comment: Do you have dates or strings?  You talk about dates but dates do not have formats.  Strings that represent dates have a format.  But then it wouldn't make sense to call `to_char` on a character string, it would only make sense to call `to_date` on character strings.  Also, what would equality look like to you?  Do you want to ignore the time component on the second value when comparing the two?

Comment: Date2 is a varchar column
Date 1 column is of type DATE

2) I want to ignore the time component of Date2. I just want to check if the two dates are unequal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably easiest to use `substr` and truncate the timestamp from the `date2` column.  Then you can use `to_date` to compare:

```
select *
from sometable
where date1 <> to_date(substr(date2,1,10), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8302a2/1)

Comment: Thanks . I am not getting any errors. But the two dates are being treated differently. I want 30-JAN-14 and 2014-01-30 TIME as equal. Can you please help me with this

Comment: @user2133404 -- did you review the fiddle?  It returns those as the same based on your sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You should be Date type conversion string is the same format for comparison

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
to_char(date2,'YYYY-MM-DD') <> to_char(date1,'YYYY-MM-DD')

Comment: Invalid Number - I think its in date 1

Comment: with sysdate not works this method :) he return dd/mm/yy and not dd/mm/yyyy